# Why does my Gson object keep returning null?

Tags: json, kotlin, gson

I'm trying to parse JSON data to a class but `gson.fromJson(response, bitt::class.java)` keeps returning null.

```kotlin
class bitt(@SerializedName("result")val result: String) {
  val someVal: String = "string"
  fun method() {
    print("something")
  }
}

val response: String = "{'success':true,'message':'','result':'Im a sult'}"
println(response)
val gson = Gson()
val ticker = gson.fromJson(response, bitt::class.java)
println(ticker)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

JSON always uses double quotes `"`, not single quotes `'`.  Your `response` uses single quotes, so it is not valid JSON.

As in many other languages, you can use `\"` to put a double quote in a string literal:

```
val response: String = "{\"success\":true,\"message\":\"\",\"result\":\"I'm a result\"}"
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me unfrotunately. Ticker is always null

Answer (score 0):

change to Data Class instead of Class

example from your code:

```
data class bitt(val result: String = "") {
    val someVal: String = "string"
    fun method() {
        print("something")
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't change anything. Ticker is always null

Answer (score 0):

I guess it takes long time before you get the result back
so the ticker still remain null

you can use kotlin coroutines to handle it.
or simply use callback like this

```
data class bitt(val result: String = "") {
    val someVal: String = "string"
    fun method() {
        print("something")
    }
}

fun getTicker(response: String, onComplete: (bitt) -> Unit) {
    val ticker = Gson().fromJson(response, bitt::class.java)
    onComplete(ticker)
}

val response: String = "{'success':true,'message':'','result':'Im a sult'}"
println(response)
getTicker(response){ println(it) }
```

Comment: Sadly, but no. Ticker is still null. I tried your method and get the error message: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ticker must not be null

Answer (score 0):

then you might need to use Coroutine

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines

```
data class bitt(val result: String = "") {
    val someVal: String = "string"
    fun method() {
        print("something")
    }
}

suspend fun getTicker(response: String) = Gson().fromJson(response, bitt::class.java)

fun yourMethod() {
    val response: String = "{'success':true,'message':'','result':'Im a sult'}"
    println(response)
    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
        val ticker = getTicker(response)
        println(ticker)
    }

}
```

[KotlinConf 2017 - Introduction to Coroutines by Roman Elizarov](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hfBv0a09Jc)

Comment: Thank you for all your help, unfortunately I couldn't get over that problem nad I have no idea what caused it. I wrote a function to which I pass a json and there I manually parse it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333603/why-cant-i-fetch-nested-data-from-json-using-gson/61432182#61432182