# Why can't I fetch nested data from json using Gson?

Tags: java, json, kotlin, gson

I have a json I fetch from an API that looks like this:

```
{"success":true,"message":"","result":{"Bid":6886.97100000,"Ask":6891.58500000,"Last":6891.58500000}}
```

**All I want is to just save Bid and Ask values in fields of a class.**

First I parse whole json like this:

```
   val response = sendRequest(url))
   val gson = Gson()
   val ticker : MarketTickerEntity = gson.fromJson(response, MarketTickerEntity::class.java)
```

And then I try to parse it inside of my class init block and reassign to bid and ask fields.

My class:

```
class MarketTickerEntity(@SerializedName("result")val result: JsonObject? = null) : TickerEntity {

  override val fee: Double = 0.0001
  override var bid: Double = 0.0
  override var ask: Double = 0.0

  data class ResultData (
    val Bid: Double,
    val Ask: Double,
    val Last: Double
  )

  init {
    if(result != null) {
      val gson = Gson()
      val res: ResultData = gson.fromJson(result, ResultData::class.java)
      bid = res.Bid
      ask = res.Ask
    }
  }

}
```

But unfortunately result is always null.

I have tried changing JsonObject? to String? in result type and then I get the error:

```
Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 40 path $.result
```

Comment: Does it make difference if you use a constant result value like `"result":"{\"Bid\":6886.97100000,\"Ask\":6891.58500000,\"Last\":6891.58500000}"`?

Comment: `fromJson` expects a `String` or another type of `Reader`. It seems you're passing it a preparsed object.

Comment: @AhmetOZKESEK No it does not make any diffrence, still same problem

Comment: @AlexeySoshin and it receives a String I checked that. Maybe it is a problem with parsing a json that was already parsed from json. But I changed whole response to "{\"success\":true,\"message\":\"\",\"result\":\"hello\"}" and it is still null. Maybe it is a problem with parsing a String then?

Comment: Response is surely a String, but result in init block is null.

Comment: The error you posted doesn't really match your models. It says it expects your "results" to be a string, but according to you model they are a `JsonObject`. So the error shouldn't be this one. Are you sure you're still getting it?

Comment: @Fred yeah I changed it to String and was getting the error I wrote. I have decided to handle that task a diffrent way and manually parse a json I get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get over it so I wrote my own function manually parsing a json I pass.

```
  override fun receiveJson(json: String){
    val gson = Gson()
    val tickerJson: JsonObject = gson.fromJson(json, JsonObject::class.java)
    val resultJson: JsonObject = gson.fromJson(tickerJson.get("result"), JsonObject::class.java)
    bid = resultJson.get("Bid").asDouble
    ask = resultJson.get("Ask").asDouble
  }
```